# What does this line in the function do?

Tags: javascript, hex, rgb

Ok, so I have this function, I just want to break down what exactly it is returning.

```
function componentToHex(c) {
    var hex = c.toString(16);
    return hex.length == 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
}
```

Let's assume: `c = 76`

And therefore:

```
c.toString(16) = 4c
```

So what is the next bit doing?

Comment: Try passing a value less than 16 to the function and see what happens. You should also read about [the ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) if that's your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is returning the result of a  [Conditional (Ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), which checks the length of the string `hex` and returns either `0` plus the string `hex` or the string `hex`.

In a long version it is this:

```
if (hex.length == 1) {
    return "0" + hex;
} else {
    return hex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

most likely it is used in color codes context and converting a color component (red, green or blue) to it's hexadecimal representation. Then, if the result is one digit, it prepends a zero in order to finally get, when all components have been converted a six character hex color code.